# CSS: Select items that contain and vertical align

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Do you know how to select divs that contain *WORD* in ID vía CSS? +1 Button adds iframes with ID "___plusone_1", the last name increases on each button and I want to apply a CSS Rule for all *plusone* tags.

```
#___*PLUSONE* {
  width:100px;
}
```

Also I want to center vertically the text from the image

[image: http://i.imgur.com/Te4q1.png]

Here's the JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aGEdu/

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a [substring-matching attribute selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#attribute-substrings) as `id` is a regular HTML attribute just like any other, with the sole downside of losing [specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#specificity):

```
div[id^="___plusone"] {
    width: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Can you check the question and answer it again? PS: Your current answer is good but I need the other part

Comment: @Luis [It can be achieved like this](http://jsfiddle.net/Shef/aGEdu/1/), but you should not mix questions. Ask it in a thread of its own.

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't accept this answer for 8 minutes and I had the other question. Thanks @Shef